# My HTML input field is "readonly" by default since the last chrome update

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, input

Several users of my website came to explain to me that it was no longer possible to click on the checkboxes or to click on the "add a file" button (input type file)

I failed to reproduce the problem until I updated Google chrome to version 92.0.4515.107

**And I could see that one of my CSS class override the default parameters because Google chrome considers my inputs as read only inputs**

https://jsfiddle.net/Lfjctwb1/

**Example :**

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="confirm-checkbox" required="">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="confirm-checkbox">
    <strong>I confirm</strong>
  </label>
</div>

<br>
<br> 

<input type="file" name="my_file" required />
```

**My CSS class that override :**

```
.disabled, input:read-only {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

How to modify my class without having to modify all my inputs ?

Comment: Ok, never mind my previous comment. I just found out I didn't have the update myself yet. WOW! That is indeed a bad, bad change that might break many things... It looks like form elements that are not in a `<form>` tag are getting treated as readonly by default now?

Comment: @ConstantinGroß there is nothing else in the code that causing it. I just confirmed after chrome update it triggers `:read-only`. @Rocstar, perhaps instead of `:read-only` you could use `[readonly]` selector. Also do you really need that class at all?

Comment: You may have actually found a bug in Chrome... But so far I haven't found any impact on any of my own projects... Still trying to figure out what's happening here! Very interesting!

Comment: You might want to create a ticket over at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium

Comment: @ConstantinGroß Thank you for your interest, the input [readonly] is working !

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything with a quick search, but I would wager your form isn't being served over HTTPS and so chrome is blocking it as a possible security risk. How are you serving the page?

Comment: @JohnPavek, that's not the case.  Single `<input>`  without form on HTTPS with provided CSS has the same issue.

Comment: I was looking for a similar thing and suspected it was a chrome bug. I had a readonly css style on my button apply in chrome. I tried edge (chromium) and it was fine, but needed an update. I ran the updated and the styles appeared.

Comment: Not every input type is affected. Only some. Issue reported: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1259187

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected per spec and won't be fixed.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-readonly
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selector-read-only

More information: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1259187